# Asp.Net MVC3 Razor help, the wrong _ViewStart.cshtml is being called

Tags: asp.net-mvc, layout, asp.net-mvc-3, razor

I have a controller 'QUnitController', then I have a folder in my Views folder 'QUnit'. In that folder I have a _ViewStart.cshtml thats coded to use the _Layout file within this folder for the Views in the QUnit folder. For some reason the _ViewStart.cshtml in the Views folder is being called and not my _ViewStart.cshtml within the QUnit folder. What am I doing wrong here?  I thought having this file in the folder would override the one in the route. I can place break points in the _ViewStart files and I see the one I want is never being hit.  Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Here is controller code. QUnitController.cs

```
 public class QUnitController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult LoadView(string viewName)
    {
        return View(viewName);
    }
}
```

Here is route Views/_ViewStart.cshtml

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";

}
```

Here is qunit Views/QUnit/_ViewStart.cshtml

```
@{
    Layout = "~/Views/QUnit/_Layout.cshtml";

}
```

Why am I not calling the correct _ViewStart? Can anyone help me correct the problem? I appreciate any help or tips anyone may have.

Thanks,
~ck in San Diego

Comment: What's the exact path to the view?

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with what you are doing. Double check your filenames, make sure there are extra whitespace etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All _ViewStart files in every parent folder are executed; the outermost one is executed first.

Your `~/Views/QUnit/_ViewStart.cshtml` should be executed last.

Are you sure that your view is coming from the correct folder?

Comment: This is correct; outermost _viewstart, then my _viewstart is called. I had logic in the outer and the inner was not being hit. I have corrected the problem. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Each area calls its own _ViewStart.cshtml. So in multi-areas context, we need to copy the _ViewStart.cshtml in the ~/View to ~/Areas/YourArea/Views.